# Bootstrap col-xs-6 (two columns) always stacks. Will not layout side by side on iPhone SE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want the two images to sit side by side when displayed on the iPhone SE (320px X 568px), however the images always stack.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="/assets/img/appointment/wp.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="/assets/img/appointment/sp.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I even tried scaling down the images thinking there might have been some over flow

```
.col-xs-6 img {
    max-width: 40%;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

All col-xs classes has deleted in Bootstrap 4, you should replace col-xs-6 with col-6.

You can see here [**notable changes**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#beta-3-changes) of bootstrap

Comment: Youu ... arre ... myy number 1, guuuyy

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use padding class of bootstrap 4 to remove extra padding which is stacking up images

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZVyEXM

```
<div class="container-fluid  pl-0 pr-0">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong:

**1)** On **Bootstrap 4** `col-xs-*` classes has been replaced by just `col-*` classes

**2)** You will need to use class `img-fluid` on your images if you want they to fit nicely on they containers (in this case the `col-*` classes).

Check the next example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 border border-danger">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 border border-danger">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, on this example, the classes `mx-auto d-block` are used for horizontally centering of images. The `border` classes are just used for visual help.